# Async await TCP Server for concurrent connection with database calls

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpserver

I have to write asynchronous TCP Server on to which multiple GPS Devices will be connecting simultaneously (Count :- 1000 Approx) and will push some data of size less than 1 Kb on server, In the response server will send them simple message containing byte received count, The same procedure will happen every 5 Min.

The data received at server is in CSV Format and contains many decimal values, server suppose to process this data and insert the same into database table

After doing lots of Google I decided to go with C#4.5 async and await methods, 
This is the first time I am implementing the TCP Server, I believe this is not really the efficient and professional code so any small of small inputs for the same are greatly appreciated. My sample code is as below

```
// Server starts from Here
public async void Start()
{
    IPAddress ipAddre = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.5");
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddre, _listeningPort);
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
              HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    } 
  }


// Handle the incoming connection and call process data 
private async void HandleConnectionAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    try
    {
        using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream, Encoding.Default))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
        {
            networkStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
            networkStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;
            char[] resp = new char[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadAsync(resp, 0, resp.Length);
                string dataFromServer1 = new string(resp);

                string status = await  ProcessDataReceived(dataFromServer1);
                if (status.Length != 0)
                    await writer.WriteAsync(status);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp){}
}

//Process Data Function 
private async Task<string> ProcessDataReceived(string dataFromServer)
{
    List<string> values = dataFromServer.Split(',').ToList();
    // Do some calculation and rearrange the data 
    // Create the datatable and insert the data into datatable

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_dbConn))
    {
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(table);
    }

     return “status”;
 }
```

At present, I have tested it with single GPS Devices and its working for some 10-15 min. than simply crashed and I am very much doubt full about its in the way it will work when there are multiple concurrent connection.

I just want to Make sure whether my basic approach as show in code is in right direction? Am I processing data in correct way or should I suppose to make the use of queue or some other data structure for processing?

Any inputs are greatly appreciable.

Comment: You could do better than an error description of "crashed". There will be a real Exception with much more information available than you are supplying. What is it?

Comment: @spender It doesn't throw any exception at all .. It simply stops and no client can connect or communicate with it.

Comment: So, you're probably tight spinning on that loop because the other side hung-up, and you didn't break out of the loop. See my answer.

Comment: BTW, that's not a crash, it's a hang.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of information means that I'm unable to tell whether this is your actual problem, but as far as problems go, this one's a biggy.

So you're not checking if the other end finished. This is indicated by [a return value of `0` when calling `ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested if the number of bytes currently available is less than the requested number, or it can be 0 (zero) if the end of the stream has been reached.

When this condition is detected, you need to get out of the loop, otherwise bad stuff will happen...

```
while(true)
{
    //....
    var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadAsync(resp, 0, resp.Length); //bad name!
    if(dataFromServer == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    //....
}
```

As a rule, when you're doing network programming, you need to trap every possible exception and understand what that exception means. Looking at failure in terms of "oh... it crashed" won't get you very far at all. Network stuff fails all the time and you have to understand why it's failing by reading all the diagnostic information you have to hand.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I would like to know the data processing stuff which i am doing in  ProcessDataReceived() is the correct way... should it be async method?

Comment: Yes, it should be async. [SqlBulkCopy has async methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485668%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so use them. As a rule, don't block during async continuations if you can possibly avoid it. That work will get scheduled (in the best case) in the ThreadPool, which isn't designed for long-lived, blocking payloads.